# How to Round a number separated by space in c#?

Tags: c#, rounding, number-formatting

I have a number in the following format:

```
string num = "66 277";
Double n = Double.parse(num);

string num1 = "108 577";
Double n1 = Double.parse(n1);
```

Now I want to round these numbers after being converted from string to double.

I used `Math.Round()` method but it gave "Invalid Number Format Exception". Then I replaced the "space" by "."(66.277 & 108.577) and used:

```
n = Math.Round(n,2);
n1 = Math.Round(n1,2);
```

this returns n=66.28 and n=108.58.

I want the output as n=66.3 and n1=109.

How can I do this? Also, suggest me if there is a way by which I don't need to remove space and directly round up the values.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the following code:

```
string num = "66 277";
Double n = Double.Parse(num, new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = " "});
Double nRounded = Math.Round(n, 1);

string num1 = "108 577";
Double n1 = Double.Parse(num1, new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = " " });
Double n1Rounded = Math.Round(n1, 1);
```

Let me explain what this does. Your first requirement was to use the space as the decimal separator. You can change this by calling the `Double.Parse` overload that takes in an `IFormatProvider` instance with a new instance of the `NumberFormatInfo` class. This class has a property called `NumberDecimalSeparator` which you can set to any string you like. In your case you can set it to a space.

The second part is that you want to round to one decimal. You can achieve this by calling `Math.Round` with `1` as the second parameter, which is the number of digits to round to.

You verify that this works in this .NET fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/9bV0HA